# How to use python 32bit under osx with Aptana studio

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, 32bit-64bit, aptana3

Following this thread: [Psycopg2 under osx works on commandline but fails in Aptana studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571495/psycopg2-under-osx-works-on-commandline-but-fails-in-aptana-studio)

I have the exact same issue.
I couldnt find/understand how to use 32 bit python in Aptana.
Running the same .py file in terminal works fine

Answer (score 1):

Download the 32 bit version of Python and add it as your interpreter for Python.

There's a detailed guide with pictures on how to do it under Ubuntu, the process for OS X is likely similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/233740/configure-python-2-7-3-interpreter-in-aptana-studio

EDIT: To find out what version of Python Aptana is using, run

```
import sys
print(sys.version) #under python 3
print sys.version #under python 2.7
```

If you're not sure whether you're using Python 3 or 2.7, try both and see which one works.

Comment: That didnt help. How Can I tell if my interpreter is trully 32 bit or not?

Comment: Were you able to make any progress on this?

Comment: it helped, it wasnt the solution yet I have found by using sys.version that the interpreter of Aptana was 2.7.2, not 2.7.4 as the one used in shell. I fixed that, now its ok

Answer (score 1):

If you open a terminal, you can check:

```
$ file /usr/bin/python
```

and see the available architectures you have.  It is likely that the binary supports more than one architecture.

Have you already tried using?

```
arch -i386 /usr/bin/python
```

as interpreter in Aptana, or setting the environment variable `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT` or just forcing the 32 bits version:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
```

You can define the environment variable in the *Preference* window, section *Interpreter - Python* → *Environment*